# How to use TraceView for memory profiling for android application

Tags: android, memory-leaks, memory-management, trace, memory-profiling

I am referencing [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debugging/debugging-tracing.html) to memory profiling of my application, when I launched `TraceView` with my trace file, there are several colors and items shows on TraceView window.

So how can I understand where memory leaks, and what is means  of colors.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/index.html  Bookmarked

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/preparing.html    http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/publishing.html   https://market.android.com/apps/GAME_WIDGETS/   http://www.zong.com/help/merchant  http://zong.com/merchants/get-started

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you should use *TraceView* for memory leaks finding. It's a tool for getting information about performance and memory usage of applications. Try [Memory Analyzer Plugin for Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/). You can make a dump of your app's memory with *Dump HPROF file* button in *DDMS* and look for memory leaks in this dump using MAT.

**UPDATE:**
When the memory dump is made you'll see *MAT*'s **Getting Started Wizard** with **Leak Suspects Report** radio button checked. Click *Finish* button and you'll see **Leak Suspects** window. There will be a diagram of memory usage and a list of potential leaks. Some leaks are false-positive. If you think that a particular leak is the real one, you can click on a *Detail* link to get more information about this leak.

When the *Detail* tab opens you will see a path to a leaked object. You can click any objects in the path and get some useful information about these objects. For example you can get a list of objects that have a reference to the selected object (*List objects* -> *with outgoing reference*).

Comment: Ok can you explain how can I understand results of Dump HPROF? please

Comment: I added some info to the answer. Please ask additional questions if you need.